# Contactually API Contact issue

Tags: php, api

I have mostly done with API request it running successfully, but having issue with "
extended_contact_data_attributes" specified in http://developers.contactually.com/docs/ .

I am not getting how to send Extended contact data. Below is my code

```
$contact = new Services_Contactually_Contact($client);

            $phone_arr = array(Array('label' => 'Phone number','value' => $phone_number));
            $params = array(
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'email' => $email,
                'visible' => 1,
                'first_contacted' => date('c'),
                'last_contacted' => date('c'),
                'hits' => 1,
                'user_bucket_id' => '248989', # new user basket id
                'extended_contact_data_attributes' => Array(
                    'phone_numbers' => $phone_arr
                )
            );

            $result = $contact->create($params);
```

Please help where I am doing wrong. API returning me error message.

`Invalid parameters. Extended contact data is improperly formatted.`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually a user of contactually or its api, but from looking through the docs, I have a feeling that your problem is in `'label' => 'Phone number'`. From the context of the docs, I would hazard a guess that there's a specific set of values that are valid for the label, such as 'Office' or 'Home' (I don't know what the actual value might be). Try replacing `'Phone number'` with `'Office'` and let me know if that still returns the same error..